# How can I create a 2D camera with zoom and parallax scrolling that works on every Windows Phone resolution?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Mario game that uses parallax scrolling: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=de5f3mvRyIY

I want to create a Windows Phone jump-and-run game with parallax scrolling. The parallax scrolling should be like in this Mario game. The character should be centered in the viewport.
I use the code of this tutorial to create the camera and parallax scrolling:
http://www.david-gouveia.com/portfolio/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/

I can zoom in and zoom out with the camera and the player(basketball) is in the center of the viewport, but parallax scrolling isn’t working correctly on every Windows Phone resolution. I get different results on every resolution. The backgrounds look different on every resolution.

For example:

WVGA emulator(resolution: 800x480pixel): http://s1.directupload.net/images/140730/ljbsolu2.png

720p emulator(resolution: 1280x720pixel): http://s1.directupload.net/images/140730/36ic4rfo.png

If you compare both pictures, you see that the backgrounds are not on the same place on both resolutions when the basketball touches the orange rectangle.

Why are the background layers not on the same place in both pictures?

I use the same sprites and same coordinates for the sprites on every Windows Phone resolution. In the WVGA picture, I just zoomed out with the camera so that you can see the entire background.
How can I create a Windows Phone game that uses parallax scrolling and looks on every resolution the same? The background layers should be on the same place on every resolution.

Comment: Different screen ratio might cause accumulate error. Since you cannot scale between two ratios with "adding something" to that empty space, I imagine that "something" has accumulated.

Comment: Is there a better way to do parallax scrolling so that the background layers look always the same on every Windows Phone device?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry - I used shaders for parallax but did not need it to be synced(so i didnt check if it is synced). I just had an idea what you might look into (does it run currectly if you reduce screen to something with matching ratio?).

Comment: How can I do that? I tried to change the zoom of the camera and I changed the starting position of the basketball but the background is always different on other resolutions.